# Opening a file using MSHTA quits unexpectedly

Tags: excel, vba

I’m trying to open a file using the following code

```
Set wShell=CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set oExec=wShell.Exec("mshta.exe ""about:<input type=file id=FILE><script>FILE.click();new ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject').GetStandardStream(1).WriteLine(FILE.value);close();resizeTo(0,0);</script>""")
tmp = oExec.StdOut.ReadLine
```

But it will crash the Excel.
I tried to wrap it on ‘’On Error Resume Next’’ and try to check its Err.Number and Err.Description but it still crashes on the ‘’Set oExec’’

Comment: Where from did you extract this piece of code? What kind of file do you try opening? Why do you need `oExec` object?

Comment: I’m using it in a .vbs which works fine. For now, I just want to capture the name of the file selected by doing ‘oExec.StdOut.ReadLine’ but I didn’t include it since the issue is on Set part. I have modified it now to include this.

Comment: Do you want/need a script able to browse and return the chosen file? Or what? I can supply such a piece of code. If needed, do you need the browse window to be filtered for specific file extensions? Anyhow, "the name of the file" is a string not an object. And only objects are `Set` in VBA/VBScript.... Then, do you want using it in VBA? I am asking that looking to the question tags. A function I am talking about will also work in VBA without any modifications...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I correctly understood your question, please use the next function:

```
Function BrowseForFile() As String
  BrowseForFile = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Exec( _
    "mshta.exe ""about:<input type=file id=f>" & _
    "<script>resizeTo(0,0);f.click();new ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject')" & _
    ".GetStandardStream(1).WriteLine(f.value);close();</script>""" _
  ).StdOut.ReadLine()
End Function
```

It can be also used in VBScript, only deleting its return declaration. I mean, `Function BrowseForFile()` (without `As String`).

It can be tested with the next Sub:

```
Sub testVBScriptBrowse()
  Debug.Print BrowseForFile
End Sub
```

But, if you are not so in love with VBScript, in VBA you can use simpler `Dialog` windows to browse for files or folders. I can also show such a piece of code if needed.

Comment: Knowing about the Dialog is also better. Thanks for pointing this.